# Eloquent model 'with' call inside the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have a `Post` model that `hasMany` `Comment` model. So basically to get the comments I would do `$post->comments`.

On some websites, I have seen people do this in the controller:

```
$post = App\Post::with('comments')->findOrFail($id);

return view('someview', compact('post'));
```

and then inside the view:

`@foreach($post->comments as $comment)` ...

To my understanding, `$post->comments` would always have the comments attached and there's no need to call `with('comments')`. Is this not correct?

If so, then what is the difference between the above and the below:

Controller

```
$post = App\Post::findOrFail($id);

return view('someview', compact('post'));
```

View

`@foreach($post->comments as $comment)` ....

Comment: With eager loading you get faster response time, And less server load while on the other hand the 2nd approach you'd have what's called N+1 issue where for each row you'll have to run a new query take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Eager Loading: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Eager loading will have no affect on your example. Here is a better use case:

```
$posts = App\Post::orderBy('id')->take(10)->get();

foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    echo $post->comments;
}
```

Eloquent will create 11 queries to the database which is not good.
1 query to get the posts, and 10 queries to get the comments for each post.

When you eager load your relation(s), Eloquent will only make one other query.

```
$posts = App\Post::with('comments')->orderBy('id')->take(10)->get();

foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    echo $post->comments;
}
```

This example will create 2 queries: 1 to get all posts and another to get the posts' comments.

```
select * from posts

select * from comments where post_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

Comment: Ah right! So I've been using eager loading blindly and now it clarifies everything, thank you!